# Простой пример Сокета. Андроид

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Недавно узнал что такое сокет но не могу о них понять некоторы моменты. Гуглил но все что нашел не расчитано для новичков. Там задействуют сервисы открывают три потока подряд и вся эта фигня. Простой пример если не жалко как создать соединение с сокетам и оброботать сообщения от сервера.

Comment: https://github.com/lampaa/ssocket посмотрите мою обертку. В целом принцип такой: при подключении клиента к серверу создается клиент-сокет, на сервере соответственно создается сервер-сокет (клиент-сокет и сервер-сокет в своём виде одинаковые). Оба сокета между собой могут общаться, т.е. отправлять и принимать данные друг другу.

Comment: @lampa то есть, если твой пример загрузить на сервер, он будет работать?

Comment: @lampa А если у меня клиент на ява а сервер на php это как то меняет дело?